# Unable to install g++

Tags: linux-mint, g++

How to fix this:

```
sahil@sahil-XPS-L501X ~ $ sudo apt-get install g++ 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation
or if you are using the unstable distribution that
some required packages have not yet been created 
or been moved out of Incoming. The following information
may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
g++ : Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: g++-4.8 (>= 4.8.1-4~) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc-4.8 (>= 4.8.1-4~) but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package

sahil@sahil-XPS-L501X ~ $ sudo apt-cache policy g++ gcc g++-4.8 gcc-4.8
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3
  Version table:
     4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
gcc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3
  Version table:
     4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
g++-4.8:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.8.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4.8.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     4.8.1-10ubuntu9 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.8.1-10ubuntu8 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
gcc-4.8:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.8.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4.8.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     4.8.1-10ubuntu9 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.8.1-10ubuntu8 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Post the output of `apt-cache policy g++ gcc g++-4.8 gcc-4.8`. In the question, not in a comment. And run `apt-cache policy` on any other packages that you think relevant.

Comment: Here is the output:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UsU6QHQ13GCxGPvvUP3uzY_nMLc4SJGC9Wx10Zo4OkI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Paste it in the question, not in a different place. Also, you must have a mistake in typing it - you have dozens of packages in there. It should just reference the package names you used as arguments. Try again.

Comment: You'll need always perform a `apt-get update` before you install new packages.

Comment: @bersch Still doesn't work.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Added in question

Comment: Ok, your output looks very odd. Paste the following output. 1) `dpkg -C`. If it gives nothing, say do. 2) Run `apt-get update` and then run the `apt-cache policy` line again. If there is no difference, say so.

Comment: The `g++ : Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.8.1-2ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: g++-4.8 (>= 4.8.1-4~) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: gcc-4.8 (>= 4.8.1-4~) but it is not going to be installed` makes no sense to me. Why is there a mix of versions of gcc in there?

Comment: OK, also paste the output of `apt-cache show g++`.

Comment: The `http://ppa.launchpad.net` line looks like it may be causing problems. Why it is there? Comment it out in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, then `apt-get update` and try running the `apt-get install g++` again.

Comment: Notice the candidates for g++-4.8 and gcc-4.8 are `4.8.2-1ubuntu1`, which is not consistent with `g++` and `gcc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming something went wrong with debian packages,
try following:

```
dpkg  -l|grep -v ^ii
```

This lists all packages which are not installed properly.

```
dpkg -P package
```

Deinstall (Purge) the affected package.

```
dpkg -P --force-all package
```

Try force if it is still resistant.

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Try to refresh all still not configured packages.

```
apt-get update
```

Update always before you install new packages.

```
apt-get install package
```

Should now be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Install `gcc` before installing `gcc-c++`

sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install gcc-c++

You can find more information about the missing dependencies with `apt-cache rdepends gcc`

Make sure you run `apt-get update` first

Comment: doesn't work.
I get this:Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gcc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc' has no installation candidate

Comment: does not work Cant install gcc as well..